# Connect phone audio with raspberrypi

Tags: android, linux, raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to make a google home assistant using RPI 3b. However, all 4 of my USB ports have suddenly stopped working. So I thought of maybe using a phone as a mic that would interact with the RPI. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as your question seems like you are looking for a tutorial which is off-topic here. Also check https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ and do check their [on topic subjects](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) should you wish to post there.

Comment: You can connect Pi to Internet via some external services like Blynk or Ubidots and give input from any device.

Comment: @AppajiChintimi Hi, I am actually looking for a way that does not include third party apps. I thought of mumble, but not sure if that is a viable option.

Comment: Well, I didn't heard of mumble. Seems like a good choice. Thanks